# time_bucket_gapfill returns empty result if raw data is missing

Tags: timescaledb

I have the following dataset

```
timeseries=# select * from ts_values where id = '32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,]' limit 10;
             time              |                  id                  | value | type | quality
-------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+------+---------
 2020-12-17 13:59:56.503654+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     1 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:52.472668+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     0 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:48.472304+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     1 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:44.472265+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     0 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:40.472345+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     1 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:36.472545+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     0 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:32.472802+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     1 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:28.472272+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     0 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:24.457489+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     1 | \x01 |
 2020-12-17 13:59:20.456482+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |     0 | \x01 |
(10 rows)
```

I try to use time_bucket_gapfill on this data but i see some behavior i don't understand.

First an example that works:

```
timeseries=# SELECT
timeseries-#   time_bucket_gapfill(INTERVAL '1 second', time) as time1s,
timeseries-#   id,
timeseries-#   locf(min(value), (SELECT value FROM ts_values where time < '2020-12-17 13:59:40' AND id = FOO.id order by time desc limit 1)) AS locf_value
timeseries-# FROM ts_values as FOO
timeseries-# WHERE
timeseries-#   time > '2020-12-17 13:59:40'
timeseries-#   AND time < '2020-12-17 13:59:44'
timeseries-#   AND id = '32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,]'
timeseries-# GROUP BY 1,2;
         time1s         |                  id                  | locf_value
------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------
 2020-12-17 13:59:40+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |          1
 2020-12-17 13:59:41+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |          1
 2020-12-17 13:59:42+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |          1
 2020-12-17 13:59:43+00 | 32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,] |          1
```

as long as there are data points in the range of the gapfill it produces data, but as the following shows
if no data is availble in the range it produces nothing.

```
timeseries=# SELECT
timeseries-#   time_bucket_gapfill(INTERVAL '1 second', time) as time1s,
timeseries-#   id,
timeseries-#   locf(min(value), (SELECT value FROM ts_values where time < '2020-12-17 13:59:41' AND id = FOO.id order by time desc limit 1)) AS locf_value
timeseries-# FROM ts_values as FOO
timeseries-# WHERE
timeseries-#   time > '2020-12-17 13:59:41'
timeseries-#   AND time < '2020-12-17 13:59:43'
timeseries-#   AND id = '32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,]'
timeseries-# GROUP BY 1,2;
 time1s | id | locf_value
--------+----+------------
(0 rows)
```

shouldn't the time_bucket_gapfill produce data with the specified resolution no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

`time_bucket_gapfill` needs to know possible grouping value to be able to gapfill. It uses actual data returned by the query before applying `gapfill`. So for the query under question it will be something like:

```sql
SELECT
  time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 second', time) as time1s,
  id,
  locf(min(value), (SELECT value FROM ts_values where time < '2020-12-17 13:59:41' AND id = FOO.id order by time desc limit 1)) AS locf_value
FROM ts_values as FOO
WHERE
  time > '2020-12-17 13:59:41'
  AND time < '2020-12-17 13:59:43'
  AND id = '32:6:1000001[2230041747,1346634600,]'
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

I suggest to check the actual `EXPLAIN` for the gapfill query.

In the question query there are two grouping columns: `time_bucket_gapfill(INTERVAL '1 second', time) as time1s` and `id`. `time_bucket_gapfill` calculates possible values for `time1s` based on the arguments to it and the time ragne derived from the WHERE clause. However, it cannot calculate possible values for `id`, since the query doesn't return any results, i.e., the set of the grouping values for `id` is empty, leading to the empty result.

**EDIT**
Several solutions are possible, but each of them will provide different semantics.

1. Remove the second grouping column, which will result in gapfill for every second. The result of `locf_value` will be NULL, since the subquery returns empty result due to no records selected from `FOO`.
2. Increase the data range top include some data.
3. Increase the data range as in 2, but provide the start and finish explicitly to `time_bucket_gapfill`, so the gapfilled records will be only for the targeted range.

Comment: But if I remove the ID, the locf will not work.

Comment: @schultz Your subquery in `locf` will return null, since there is no records of `FOO` satisfies the outer condition. It is not related to grouping on `id`.